# Google OAuth Verification setting an authorized domain outside of app domain

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I am developing an app as part of a research project and need to submit it to Google for verification. Our privacy policy is not hosted on the same domain as the app (though we do link to it) it is instead hosted on the domain for the university. In my OAuth consent screen configuration in the developers console if I list the university domain under the "Authorized domains" for our app, will this interfere in anyway with the university's website while google is verifying the app? Sorry if this question is trivial I just want to make absolutely sure doing so will not get our team into trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Google OAuth Verification does not interfere in any way with the website. This is just a security measure to only allow your authorized domains from within the consent screen.